# Query appears to return a result but with null values

Tags: php, mysql

I've got an Android project that uses a MySQL database for user registration and login. The registration portion works as expected. The login portion does not. Here's the thing, they both use the same EXACT query to check if an email address already exists. The registration checks to make sure that a user isn't already using that email address before storing the user. The login uses the same query to pull a hash of the encrypted password + salt to compare to the hash of the POSTED password hash. When the login portion makes the query, it returns at least one row, but it appears that all the values are null. Here's the code for where the query is:

```
// Check if user already exists.
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($email));
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
    // User exists.
    $stored_salt = $result["salt"];
    $stored_password = $result["encrypted_password"];
    $hash = crypt($password_hash, '$2a$10$'.$stored_salt);
    // Check for password equality.
    if ($stored_password == $hash) {
        // User authentication details are correct.
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["uid"] = $result["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $result["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $result["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $result["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $result["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // User authentication failed.
        // echo JSON with error = 1.
        $response["error"]     = 2;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect password!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // User does not exist.
    $response["error"] = 1;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Email address not found.";
}
```

The JSON object that is returned says "Incorrect password!", so I had it include the password that was being checked against in the JSON object, and that password is null. My assumption is that the query is not returning a result, but it passes the no_of_rows > 0 test, so it's returning something. So I included other parts of the result in the returned JSON object, and they're null as well. I also checked the query through phpmyadmin on my site (it's hosted on 1and1), and the query works there. Anyone have any insights? I'm new to both PHP and MySQL so I'm learning as I go here, but I've kind of hit a wall.

Comment: `$result` is a 'mysql result resource', you need to do something with it, ie [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please, don't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [pdo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdo) or [mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli).

Comment: @Jon Thank you, that does indeed work!

Comment: No problem ^^ Glad I could help.

Comment: @Dracs Thank you. I am aware that mysql_* functions are deprecated, but the tutorial I was following used it, so I figured I'd get everything working and then try to switch out the mysql_* functions for mysqli when I had a chance to research. All the same, I appreciate the reminder. As I understand it, mysql_* functions may very well be removed from newer versions of PHP, and if that does happen, it would likely render my code useless. Now that everything is working, this is my next task. Thanks again!

Comment: @flapjack.fiasco Just making sure you were aware of the issue. It's relatively easy to switch over to myqsli. I also just wanted it noted for anybody else who looks at the question in the future.

Comment: Good to know it's going to be easy! Thanks @Dracs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_row` to get the actual row from the rowset back.

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($email));
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
    // User exists.
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $salt = $row['salt'];
```

Comment: Awesome! mysql_fetch_row does not work, but mysql_fetch_assoc does, as does mysql_fetch_array. Thank you so much!